# Kendo grid columns disable and make enable conditionally

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I want my Kendo grid's column read-only after bind. I have a dropdownlist in my page. Depending on the selected value of the dropdownlist I want to enable editing a cell in a row selected.

Does anyone have sample code?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve the desired behavior like this:

- use the [`edit`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit) event of the Grid, check the DropDownList [`value()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-value) and if editing should be prevented, execute the Grid's [`closeCell()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-closeCell) method to exit edit mode. If the user is trying to add a new item to the Grid ([`e.model.isNew()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-isNew)), you will also need to [`remove()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-remove) this new item with the respective [`dataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-dataSource) method.
- use the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) event of the DropDownList to hide the CRUD-related buttons in the Grid with custom CSS styles.

Another possible option is to recreate and rebind the Grid with the correct editing settings via [`setOptions`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) every time the dropDownList value changes.

The example below uses the first approach described above. You can modify it, so that not only the *Delete* buttons are toggled, but also *Add New Record*.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing/">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title>Kendo UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
      .hideDeleteButtons .k-grid-delete {
         visibility: hidden;
      }
      
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">

      <p><label for="dropdownlist">Grid editing is:</label>
        <select id="dropdownlist"><option value="1">enabled</option><option value="0">disabled</option></select></p>

      <div id="grid"></div>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
           change: function(e) {
             $("#grid").toggleClass("hideDeleteButtons", e.sender.value() !== "1");
            }
          });

          var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
              dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                  read:  {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                  },
                  update: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                  },
                  destroy: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                  },
                  create: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                  },
                  parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                      return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                  }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                  model: {
                    id: "ProductID",
                    fields: {
                      ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                      ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
                      UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                      Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                      UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
                    }
                  }
                }
              });

          $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            pageable: true,
            height: 300,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [
              { field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name" },
              { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 200 }],
            editable: true,
            edit: function(e) {
              var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
              if (dropdownlist.value() !== "1") {
                e.sender.closeCell();
                if (e.model.isNew()) {
                  e.sender.dataSource.remove(e.model);
                }
              }
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think he can also use the editor option (function) per column and inside the editor function he can call closeCell() conditionally or return the appropriate container , so he have more control over which column to disable editing or enable editing